# Django error browser is unable to connect at 127.0.0.1:8000/products/

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am creating my first Django project. I have successfully installed Django version 2.1. When I created the project, the project was successfully launched at the url 127.0.0.1:8000.
Then I ran the command **python manage.py startapp products**.
Products folder was also successfully created in the project. Then inside the products folder, I opened: 
**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello World')
```

then **products/urls**:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index)
]
```

Inside the main project folder, I opened **urls.py** and I modified the code:

```
  from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('products/', include('products.urls'))
]
```

Then the url **http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/** was not opening on browser. Browser is giving the "Unable to connect" error. I am using the PyCharm IDE. I will really appreciate your answer.

Comment: have you added your app name in installed apps?

Comment: Is the dev server still running or giving an error?

Comment: When I enter the url http://127.0.0.1:8000, the Django app successfully installed page is launched.

Comment: in settings, in INSTALLED_APPS you have to add products, preferably at the bottom

Comment: But when I try to access the products folder which is the app folder inside the main project, through url 127.0.0.1:8000/products/ the browser gives an error 'Unable to connect'

Comment: what is the error message on your dev server ? error logs?

Comment: `Then inside the products folder, inside the sub folder migrations, I opened: ...` you shouldn't be touching the `migrations` folder, and key files such as a `urls.py` and `views.py` should be at the top level of your app golder

Comment: No I didn't open that folder. Actually the **urls.py** is inside the products folder. I got that statement wrong.

Comment: **Then inside the products folder, I opened: ...**

Comment: @RobinZigmond I didn't touch the migrations folder. urls.py and views.py were below the products folder. I mistakenly wrote that statement.

Answer (score 1):

In you **settings.py** add the app to the **INSTALLED_APPS** list as:

```py
 INSTALLED_APPS =
 [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'products' # <-- your product app 
]
```

And modify **ALLOWED_HOSTS** list as:

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']
```

Then run the application:

`python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8080`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you had ran the command below:

`python manage.py runserver`

If you had run the above command and the error persists, try to run on the global address 0.0.0.0

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

OR on a different port

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
```

Comment: It's still giving the same error. Thanks for your response. I really appreciate it.