# Django Server Unable to Open Admin Page

Tags: python, django, postgresql, server, atom-editor

I am following an online course on Django, and my browser fails to load the admin page. I created a job, added it to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py, and added it in admin.py as follows:

```
from .models import Job
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Job)
```

In urls.py I believe I have the standard admin url

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', jobs.views.home, name='home'),
]
```

I'm not sure if any other any information is needed but please ask if there is anything else. I start the server using  `python manage.py runserver` and it can access /home okay, but if I change the url to admin or admin/ it says 'Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8000.'.I've tried it on different browsers and the same outcome is reached. My question is similar to the one here: [Django error browser is unable to connect at 127.0.0.1:8000/products/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59598620/django-error-browser-is-unable-to-connect-at-127-0-0-18000-products) and I tried all of the solutions there but none worked. I followed the tutorial very specifically, so I have no idea what is causing this. I am using Atom on a Windows 10 machine, the project is connected to a postgresql database.

UPDATE/EDIT 08/23/20 10:31AM PST.

Here is a screenshot of INSTALLED_APPS:
[image]

There is no error in console when I try to open admin. If I run the server as shown below and open the link http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin, the server just stops working and my command line returns to just taking in commands. Details in screenshot below.

[image]

UPDATE/EDIT 08/23/20 12:07PM PST.

[image]

Comment: Both URLs use the same connection. At the point where the error happens Django has no chance to distinguish between them. That means that there is some other problem. A former request could block the server or there is a serious problem shutting down the server. What does the console show when you make the requests?

Comment: Share the screenshot/code of `INSTALLED_APPS` as well as the error you are getting on the `console`.

Comment: `Register your models here.` must be commented by the way.

Comment: @KlausD I updated the question with more details.

Comment: Show us your `Job` model!

Comment: @KlausD. I added it!

Comment: @EricHasegawa did you happen to try uninstalling Django and installing again into your environment ? `pip uninstall Django` and `pip install Django`. Also, it's save to have a separate virtual environment for your project.

Comment: By your description, seems like something is shutting down the server whenever you enter admin url. What happens when you raise an exception on the already working urls? Like `raise ValueError('whateva')`.

Comment: How did you solve the issue @EricHasegawa ?