# Do I need to be able to access the Django admin page?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, server, django-admin

As a follow up to this question [Django Server Unable to Open Admin Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63543305/django-server-unable-to-open-admin-page), seeing as no one was able to answer, I am all out of ideas. I don't know how to solve this, and am wondering if I should just avoid using the Django admin page since the other pages work fine. Can I achieve all of the admin functionality from the command line? Alternatively, does anyone have any ideas as to how I could solve this?

Comment: Did django server stop when you log in to admin page? I encountered this error once and still not sure why. But I think it's because the OS socket, when i switch to Ubuntu, it works fine

Comment: It stopped when I loaded the admin, I can try running it in an ubuntu shell